# Display previous and next image inside popup on fancybox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to create a layout like this link [fancybox layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYZOq.jpg). The fancybox provides option to create a tpl, so far so good.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the next & previous image of the current object and pass it to a div.

I saw the callbacks listed in fancybox page http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ but I can't figure out how to do it.
Also I saw this fiddle jsfiddle.net/xW5gs/. It stores the previous image link but I was unable to pass it as a background to a div with jquery.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Edit:

I am using fancybox like this:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
        'nextEffect': 'none',
        'prevEffect': 'none',
        'tpl': {
            wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div id="prev-img"></div><div id="next-img"></div><a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
            closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close hide-me" href="javascript:;"></a>'
        },
        afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
            console.log( 'Current: ' + current.href );        
            console.log( 'Previous: ' + (previous ? previous.href : '-') );


            if (previous) {
                document.getElementById('prev-img').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+previous.href+')';// here I am trying to pass as a background the url of the previous object to the div with id #prev-img.
                console.log( 'Navigating: ' + (current.index > previous.index ? 'right' : 'left') );     
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I edit the post including a sample code. Thanks for your interest. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        'padding' : 0,
        'arrows': true,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 1000,
        'speedOut': 700,
        'helpers' : { 
            'title' : { type : 'inside',position : 'top'}
        },
        'afterShow': function () {
        // initialize some variables
        var gallerySize = this.group.length,
            next, prev,next_i,prev_i;
        if (this.index == gallerySize - 1) {
            // this is the last element of the gallery so next is the first
            next = $(".fancybox").eq(0).attr("title"),
            prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");

            next_i = $(".fancybox").eq(0).attr("href"),
            prev_i = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("href");
        } else if (this.index == 0) {
            // this is the first image of the gallery so prev is the last
            next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
            prev = $(".fancybox").eq(gallerySize - 1).attr("title");

            next_i = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("href"),
            prev_i = $(".fancybox").eq(gallerySize - 1).attr("href");
        } else {
            // otherwise just add or substract to index
            next = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("title"),
            prev = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index - 1).attr("title");

            next_i = $(".fancybox").eq(this.index + 1).attr("href"),
            prev_i = $(".fancybox").eq(gallerySize - 1).attr("href");
        }
        // set title attributes to fancybox next/prev selectors
        $(".fancybox-next").attr("title", next);
        $(".fancybox-prev").attr("title", prev);

        $(".fancybox-next").css('background-image', 'url(' + next_i + ')');
        $(".fancybox-prev").css('background-image', 'url(' + prev_i + ')');
        $(".fancybox-next").css('background-size', 'cover');
        $(".fancybox-prev").css('background-size', 'cover');

    }

    });
 })
```

You can use this code to display image on next and previous buttons.